# Cant delete some table data using sql

Tags: sql

I have a phone_book table. It has columns named id, first_name, last_name and phone. Im trying to delete all contacts with the first name of Jonathan and the last name of Luna.

My code is this

DELETE FROM phone_book WHERE first_name, last_name = "Jonathan" , "Luna";

Im getting a syntax error near the comma. Please help thanks

Comment: In the future, a quick search for something like "sql delete where clause with multiple conditions" or even "sql delete where clause" should give you relevant results. Good luck! (p.s. it looks like you should mark Joanvo's answer as correct)

Comment: Cool will do thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `WHERE` conditions separated by `AND`:

```
DELETE FROM phone_book WHERE first_name = "Jonathan" AND last_name = "Luna";
```

Comment: Thanks so much i appreciate your help